# What the rule for these questions without any subject at all?

Tags: grammar, idioms, questions, colloquial-language, wh-questions

Expressions and sources:

- Why pretend? ([Depeche mode 'Little 15'](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/depechemode/little15.html))
- Why so serious? ([Joker 'Dark knight'](https://youtu.be/F_5dP_83O7o?t=36))
- Why make sense? ([Hot Chip 'Why make sense'](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/hotchip/whymakesense.html))
- Who to be? ([Whitey 'Who to be?'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDyPBxfAUIg))
- Why try? ([Limp Bizkit 'Why try?'](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/limpbizkit/whytry.html))
- Why not go out and make a scene? ([Shamir 'Make A Scene'](https://genius.com/Shamir-make-a-scene-lyrics))

---

**Question:**

> What's the rule, in terms of grammar, for these subjectless questions (i appreciate the link to a grammar book with explanation)

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't say how long ago for sure, but for me, this I believe this usage is rather contemporary. I can't say when people started doing this but today, they do it all the time in two-person conversations.

Comment: If "rather contemporary" includes the early 19th century, then yes. https://books.google.com/books?id=DmAJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA265&dq=%22but+why+try%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcl4Sf0c3aAhXuUN8KHUOQCN8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22but%20why%20try%22&f=false

Comment: Questions and imperatives often don't really have a "subject" in the same sense that declarative sentences do.

Answer (score 1):

The absence of an explicit subject allows these questions to be asked in a variety of contexts.

Some of those sentences would mean  the following if you are directly addressing someone:

> Why are *you* pretending?
>
> Why are *you* being so serious?
>
> Why don't *you* go out and make a scene?

Or they could be actual questions about a third person:

> Why is she|he pretending? What would cause a person to pretend in that situation?
>
> Why is he|she being so serious. What's going on that he|she would be so serious now?  It seems strange for him|her|them to be so serious.

Others  could be rhetorical and refer to oneself indirectly as "one":

> Why should anyone pretend?  Why should I pretend?
>
> Who should one be? Who should I be?
>
> Why should anyone try? Why should I try?

And the most famous one of all:

> To be, or not to be?

The verb BE is often omitted. Here the subject is provided by context.

Comment: For me, these are usually directed at an interlocutor and not about a third person or oneself.

Comment: @Lambie: That's just you.  I've heard them thousands of times in all three categories. *But why try to convince you?*

Comment: I think I see what you mean but would not have expressed as you have done, that's all. It confused me. In conversation, it could refer to a person one is talking about,  yes. So, I do agree. Why [should I] pretend otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect those questions are extracted from the lyrics of songs, which are seldom reliable sources of standard English. Each one is an abbreviated form of a question with a subject, which is thus implied.

Why [should I/we/you] pretend? Why [are you/we] so serious? Why [need/should] one make sense? Who [should I/one try] to be? Why [should/does one] try? Why [do I/you/we] not go out and make a scene?